# Why is this checking for variable existence using array notation instead of dot notation?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api and it starts with:

```
if (!window['YT']) {
    var YT = {
        loading: 0,
        loaded: 0
    };
}

if (!window['YTConfig']) {
    var YTConfig = {
        'host': 'http://www.youtube.com'
    };
}
```

I don't understand why checks for variables are not using dot notation such as:

```
if (!window.YT) {
    var YT = {
        loading: 0,
        loaded: 0
    };
}

if (!window.YTConfig) {
    var YTConfig = {
        'host': 'http://www.youtube.com'
    };
}
```

Is this just personal preference? Or are there implications?

Comment: Personal preference in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are no implications in this specific example**

Common reasons to use array notation would be if the string contains special characters

```
// something like
obj["hello world"]

// or like
obj["hello-world"]
```

Another reason would be if the key you want to access is a variable

```
var foo = "hello";
obj[foo] === obj.hello;
```

Otherwise

```
// these are the same
obj.foo === obj["foo"]
```

Answer (score 1):

When the string doesn't contain any characters that can't be used in an identifier, there is no difference between accessing the property by name or using a string.

Note that the code is written as if the variables are created inside the `if` statements if they don't exist. The variables does actually always exist, as the declaration is hoisted to the beginning of the scope, so the `if` statements only checks if the variables contain a falsy value.

The author of the code perhaps thought that it would be safer to check for the existance of the variables by accessing them using a string, but there is no such difference. In this case there is no need for any such caution anyway, as the variables definitely always exist.

The code is the equivalent of:

```
var YT, YTConfig;

if (!YT) {
  YT = {
    loading: 0,
    loaded: 0
  };
}

if (!YTConfig) {
  YTConfig = {
    'host': 'http://www.youtube.com'
  };
}
```

If any of the variables did exist prior to this code, the declaration for that variable here would just be ignored, i.e. the variable won't be redeclared by a duplicate declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, there is absolutely no difference. They both access the same variables.

However, there are advantages and disadvantages to each.

## Dot notation

Personally, I use the dot notation in every single time that I don't need to use the array notation. It is much more readable with the `.` separating each object level.

`office.employees[0].empNumber` is much more readable than `office['employees'][0]['empNumber']`. (They both access the same variable)

## Array notation

There are 3 main reasons for you to use the array notation :

1. When you're accessing number-indexed arrays (*employee[0], employee[1], ...*)
2. When you need to use variables as keys (`phonelist[customerServiceID]`, where `customerServiceID` is a variable, which may be a number or a string)
3. As @naomik indicated in his answer, special characters as keys would also make you need to use the array notation instead.

Comment: There's 3 main reasons for using array notation: the two you gave and when the keys contain characters that's not valid as variable names. For example, the key `'customerService-id'`

Comment: You're right. @naomik indicated it in his answer as well. I'll include it in my answer for completeness.